# How to retrieve the value of a Checkbox in HTML via Python

Tags: python, html, checkbox

I have no real knowledge of HTML but I have to use it to make a Webview for some Data.
I want to have a button, that links to another python script to compare the Data Sets.
You are able to choose which Datasets you compare by checking a checkbox.
Then the button should bring you to the right script.
The compare function, the list of Data Sets, etc. all works, but i can't seem to get the value of the Checkboxes.
This generates the List of Checkboxes

```
    query_3 = App.QueryFactory.new("XMLQuery", xml_2 %(p1, p2, p3))
   for smlz in query_3.getAll():
    resultz += '''
<input type="checkbox" name="sml_id" value="%s"> 
<a href="http://xxx:xxx/xxxxx?sml_1=%s&gewinde=&kopf=&antrieb=&singlesearch=Suche">
%s | ID: %s |</a><br><br>''' % ( smlz.id, smlz.id, smlz.status, smlz.id)
return resultz
```

This is the code of the button:

```
comparebutton = """<td><input type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://xxxx:xxxx/xxxx?sml_1=%s&gewinde=&kopf=&antrieb=&singlesearch=Suche';" value="Vergleichen"></td>\n""" % cb_id

keyw_c = str(kwds.get("sml_id"))   
keyw_c_l =  keyw_c.split() 
key_c_len = len(keyw_c_l)
cb_id = ''
p = 0
while p < key_c_len:
    temp_1 = str(keyw_c_l[p])
    temp_2 = temp_1.strip(",[]'")
    p += 1
    cb_id += "%s_" % temp_2
```

**(Note: The _ is needed as the script i want to link to is able to show more than one Data set when dividing the Data ID's by underscores, thus "comparing" the Datasets)**

I tried get, getAll etc, to get the Value of the Checkboxes i checked, but i always get 'None'
Did i do something wrong or is it possible to make this easier by making a button that executes a certain function of my python code, since i have the code of the "compare" script, i just lack the HTML knowledge to do anything like that.

Output of kwds (I have 4 fields for input and singlesearch is the name of the searchbutton)

```
{'sml_1': ['test'], 'antrieb': ['test'], 'singlesearch': ['Suche'], 'kopf': ['test'], 'gewinde': ['test ']}
```

Comment: What - _exactly_ - is supposed to be going on in your second code snippet? What is `kwds`? Where are you getting `sml_id` since it doesn't seem to be part of your querystring?

Comment: snl_id is the name of the checkboxes, and with kwds.get("name") i got the values of the input fields etc in the webviewer, i do not really know why it is kwds.get, i got part of this code handed to me and it was used like this and worked all the times

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I use, or am required to use vpython, and only imported StringIO, so I guess no dedicated framework.

Comment: To your first comment, in the second part, i want to get the value of the Checkboxes that are checked, split it into a list and then add those ID's to the link the button sends you to when clicked, so that you'll be send to the adress with the ID's you marked

Comment: Can you show the output of `print kwds` at the start of the second code snippet? When we know better what kwds is, we can help you better. Currently, your asking us to help while you have a black box as input. If people don't know the contents of the black box, we can't help you further.

Comment: it is the name the programmer of the code gave to what normally is called kwargs at the def run( ... *kwds)

Answer (score 0):

To make a html web browser interface, you need a transport for the web browser to communicate with your application.  The transport most commonly used is http. To run a http that can run python code, there are many [options](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming). If I had to recommend something, it would be [pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/docs/pyramid.html).

Your web server should then handle different requests:

1. A url that returns the initial html form. The form can contain the checkboxes that you require. The action for this form should be the url for request num 2. The method for the form can either be a POST or a GET. With a GET, the form data is visible to the user. For a POST, it is hidden. For your use case a GET is probably better.
2. A url that handles gets from the form. It will be able to see the values of the inputs on the form (e.g. the checkboxes) by looking a the request. At this point, you can call the vpython modules to generate the desired content, and pass that on to the browser in the http response.